# Combine and Sum rows based on multiple criteria with VBA

Tags: excel, sum, rows, vba

I am a VBA novice and cannot figure out how to combine and sum rows based on certain column criteria. Say, Column B and Column C have text values while column A has number values.  Row 1 and Row 2 have the same values in Columns B and C.  I want to have these rows combined into one row with Columns B and C having the same values as before but Column A to have the sum of the previous rows.

Comment: Can you attach screen with desired result?

Comment: I am unable to attach screen shots.  Not enough points it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that row 1 contains the headers for the columns and that the rest of the rows contain only values the following code should do the trick (for sheet1):

```
Public Sub SumByTwoCriteria()
Dim lngStartRow, lngSearchRow, lngLastRow As Long

lngLastRow = Sheet1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For lngStartRow = 2 To lngLastRow
    For lngSearchRow = lngStartRow + 1 To lngLastRow
        While Sheet1.Cells(lngStartRow, 2).Value2 = Sheet1.Cells(lngSearchRow, 2).Value2 And _
            Sheet1.Cells(lngStartRow, 3).Value2 = Sheet1.Cells(lngStartRow, 3).Value2
                Sheet1.Cells(lngStartRow, 1).Value2 = Sheet1.Cells(lngStartRow, 1).Value2 + Sheet1.Cells(lngSearchRow, 1).Value2
                Sheet1.Rows(lngSearchRow & ":" & lngSearchRow).Delete
                lngLastRow = lngLastRow - 1
        Wend
    Next lngSearchRow
Next lngStartRow

End Sub
```